# Controlling Numeric Parameters from a UserForm Window in Inventor

Tags: vba, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I need help. I want to control the values of some parameters of the "Inventor" part using "UserForms", but it has reached a dead end. For starters, I have a TextBox and CommandButton and some numerical parameter Drope in mm, created in the inventor parameter table. I managed to get access to this parameter, but I can’t change it using UserForms. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
Public Sub okbtn1_Click()

    Dim partDoc As PartDocument
    Set partDoc = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument

    Dim userParams As UserParameters
    Set userParams = partDoc.ComponentDefinition.Parameters.UserParameters

    Dim oDrope As Parameter
    Set oDrope = userParams.Item("Drope")
    Drope = TextBox1

    End
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter value is always in centimeters because this is Inventor internal units.

You can convert value to cm

```
oDrop.Value = TextBox1 / 10
```

or set the parameter Expression (string) where you can specify units or default document units are used

```
oDrop.Expression = TextBox1 & "mm" ' With units [mm]
oDrop.Expression = TextBox1 ' Default document units
```

Comment: Thank You!! Elegant solution. I divided by 10 in the parameter table. I did not know what could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, but the value is entered in cm. I am looking for ways to specify it in mm.

```
Private Sub CmdButtonOk2_Click()

    Dim partDoc As PartDocument
    Set partDoc = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument

    Dim userParams As UserParameters
    Set userParams = partDoc.ComponentDefinition.Parameters.UserParameters

    Dim oDrope As Parameter
    Set oDrope = userParams.Item("Drope")
    oDrope.Value = TxtBox2

    End

End Sub
```